# How to remove <p> tag from string in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

I am getting `<p>` tag in my string . I want to remove the `<p>` and `</p>`  from string .is it possible in xslt ?

here is my code
http://xsltransform.net/ehVYZNv

```
   <xsl:variable name="bb">&lt;p&gt;Former Indian cricketer Sachin Tendulkar, who is an avid lover of Tennis, posted this cute picture with his wife Anjali Tendulkar at the Wimbledon’s semi-final match. He also wished Roger Federer all the best for the match. (Photo: Instagram)&lt;/p&gt;
          </xsl:variable>

        =====
<xsl:value-of select="$bb" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

**Expected output**

**Former Indian cricketer Sachin Tendulkar, who is an avid lover of Tennis, posted this cute picture with his wife Anjali Tendulkar at the Wimbledon’s semi-final match. He also wished Roger Federer all the best for the match. (Photo: Instagram**

Comment: Since your expected output, as per the shared code is `html` why do you need to remove the `<p>` tags. The `html` output will handle them.

Comment: change output to `text`

Comment: Please share the input XML and XSLT or correct it on the [xsltransform](http://xsltransform.net/ehVYZNv) example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use substring for that in xslt 1.0

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($bb, '&lt;p&gt;'), '&lt;/p&gt;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```